# "Time" Command in Cygwin in Windows Command Line

Tags: sql, linux, db2, cygwin

I want to run a query using db2 in WINDOWS COMMAND LINE:

code:

```
db2 connect to sample;
db2 "Select * from TB1";
```

[image]

I am currently doing the IBM Lab activity in Data Concurrency and Locking and I want to determine and quantify the waiting time of the executed command using the "time command" in linux.

I have heard of the Cygwin and successfully installed it in my computer to execute UNIX/LINUX command. I test if "Time" Command can be successfully read by windows cmd using "bash"

[image]

I tried to execute this command to get the execution time of the query:

[image]

I also tried to include the connect to database

[image]

but still it keeps on saying

> SQL1042N A database connection does not exist. SQLSTATE=08003

I am really new in DB2 and unfamiliar with Linux command... any help would bee greatly appreciated

Thank You

Comment: then read some docs.

Comment: Thats a very useful suggestion @IporSircer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try this;

create script.sql  in  "C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\" as below;

```
connect to sample;
Select * from TB1;
```

and then run this;

```
bash -c "time db2 -tvf script.sql"
```

Comment: Hi sir, appreciated your effort to help, I tried to perform what you said... it returns DB21005E An error occured while accessing the file "C:\script.sql".

Comment: @RyanAbarquez: I updaed ans. could you try this;

Answer (score 1):

I could help you with "time" and DB2, but my recommendation is look into using the command [db2batch](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002043.html). It is designed to benchmark, i.e., get timing for SQL commands. There are various options for the output.

When using "time", do you know how the reported numbers need to be interpreted?

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for this response, I have really idea about this im just following the lab instruction... can you give me an example on how to use db2batch in my query above? Thank You so much

Comment: There is the link to the docs in my answer. The docs have samples. You put your SQL statement in a file and call the command as shown in the docs.